# Using "Find" in a user defined function - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos, find

Working on (this probably relates to the problem):

Microsoft Excel for Mac, Version 15.41 (171205)

macOS High Sierra, Version 10.13.2

In order to avoid code duplication and make it more readable I tried to define my own function that locates the cell containing a column name.

It has 3 arguments:

headerName - the name of the column (ex. "ID", "Price", etc..)

sheetName - the name of the sheet to be searched in

rowNum - the number of the row where the headers of the columns are located

This is what I wrote:

```
Function findCell(headerName, sheetName, rowNum)

Set cell = _
Sheets(sheetName).Rows(rowNum).Find(headerName,LookIn:=xlValues, _
Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=True)

findCell = cell.Column

End Function
```

To be exact - I want it to return the cell and not the cell's column, I'm just using the column as a way to verify correctness.

However this doesn't work with `function` (returns `#VALUE!`) but for some reason it *does* work with `sub` (outputting with `msgbox`)...

Comment: how do you call it for a function?  Can you show an example?

Comment: Do you mean it works with a sub with exactly the same parameters?

Comment: I called it in the sheet - =findCell("SE#","Report",21). And yes it worked in with sub, just replacing the last line in `msgbox cell.column`

Comment: Your code works for me as a UDF.  Maybe you have a typo?

Comment: Checked typos, I don't see any. Maybe it relates to the fact I'm using Mac? Storax code gives me "Compile error, argument not optional" on the line with `findCell=0`

Comment: I do not see a `findCell=0` in your code above.

Comment: Storax's code doesn't give that compile error, even on a Mac. You might run into problems if you are trying to use Storax's code and your code in the same module.

Comment: Tried it on a different module, it works but it always returns 0 - which is the essence of the problem - `Find` doesn't work (in the meaning of not finding anything). My col names are at row 21 on a sheet named Report.

Comment: If the function returns 0 then ".find" did not find anything. You have to enter the header excatly as it is. "Header" and "HEADER" is not the same because of MatchCase = True.

Comment: I wrote on B20 `gyp` and then entered Storax function in the following: `=findCell("gyp", "Report", 20)`. I get 0. The sheet name is Report and not report. It's not the match

Comment: if "gyp" in B20 does contain extra spaces the function will return 0

Comment: VBA for the Mac is somewhat undersupported. It is at least possible that this is a bug in how VBA is implemented in the Mac.

Comment: No spaces lol, only gyp. I tried in a new blank workbook (changed the sheetName argument to "Sheet1" of course...) and it resulted the same. I think we are left to conclude it is probably a weird Mac issue as John mentioned. I appreciate your efforts none the less.

Comment: And it is also not a formula, just "clean" text? Though, in my Windows environment this works as well. So, I don't really know, what's wrong on a Mac with this function.

Comment: Yup clean text, typed it from scratch in a new plain workbook just to make sure. I had issues with PC/Mac - VBA compatibility before (code that worked in Windows but not in my Mac for instance) so my best guess would be it's that case, although this one is pretty weird.

Comment: I edited my answer and modfied it slightly. It's just a wild guess.

Comment: What version and build of Mac Excel are you using? (Early versions of Excel did not allow the use of Find in UDFs)

Comment: Excel - 15.41, Mac - Sierra 10.13.2 I think VBA Excel got a recent update for Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing it with another Mac on an older version of macOS and older version Microsoft Excel for Mac resulted the same (even with @Storax variants).
Testing the code I posted on PC/Windows will actually work (as mentioned in the comments by others).

This left me to conclude that this issue is a weird bug in VBA version of Mac.

My workaround - instead of defining a `function` I defined a `sub` that uses a global variable.
The `sub` is adapted from @Storax better code:

```
Public findColOut As Long


Sub findCol(ByVal headerName As String, ByVal sheetName As String, ByVal rowNum As Long)

Dim cell As Range

Set cell = Sheets(sheetName).Rows(rowNum).Find(headerName,_
LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlRows,_
SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)

If cell Is Nothing Then
   findColOut = 0
Else
   findColOut = cell.Column
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the following code works

```
Function findCell(ByVal headerName As String, ByVal sheetName As String, ByVal rowNum As Long) As Long

Dim cell As Range

    Set cell = _
    Sheets(sheetName).Rows(rowNum).Find(headerName, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                        Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                        MatchCase:=True)

    If cell Is Nothing Then
        findCell = 0
    Else
        findCell = cell.Column
    End If

End Function
```

EDIT: Just a wild guess because above function works in a windows environment.

```
Function findCell(ByVal headerName As String, ByVal sheetName As String, _
                  ByVal rowNum As Long) As Long

Dim cell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rg As Range

    Set ws = Sheets(sheetName)
    Set rg = ws.Rows(rowNum)

    '    Set cell = _
         '    rg.Find(headerName, LookIn:=xlValues, _
         '            Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
         '            MatchCase:=False)

    Set cell = rg.Find(headerName, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlRows, xlNext, True)

    If cell Is Nothing Then
        findCell = 0
    Else
        findCell = cell.Column
    End If

End Function
```

EDIT2: Another wild guess

```
Set cell = rg.Find(headerName, , &HFFFFEFBD, 1, 1, 1, True)
```

Comment: While this code is much better than OP's (declared types, dimmed variables, and checking if cell is nothing) so +1, it doesn't really explain how OP's code could work as a sub but not a UDF. There is still an unexplained mystery.

Comment: I am not sure what the OP tested but in case the .Find returns Nothing he will get #VALUE. And in case he tested the sub with a result not equal Nothing he will get a postive result. So, my asumption is he did not apply the same test.

Comment: While your dedication deservers an applause, it's still not working. The normal .Find (in your first code) does work when inserted as a `Sub` instead of a `Function`. It seems for some reason the combination of `Function` and `Find` breeds weird stuff. I assume it's a bug given with the new VBA - Mac update or just something with my own machine. Tomorrow I'll get a new machine to test this

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you.  I use this code to find a cell with the value "IB" in the field of cells that are selected.
Once it finds "IB", I change the value of the cell to "BS".
Cut that column, and insert it in another location.  Then it iterates I and goes onto the next search.

I am sure it's not elegant, but it might help you to get unstuck:

```
Cells.Select
Selection.Find(What:="IB", after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Select
Selection.Value = "BS"
MyCol = ActiveCell.Column
Columns(MyCol).Cut
Columns(i).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
i = i + 1
```