# UDF works fine in debug mode, returns #VALUE! error when used in cell

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I am trying to write a UDF to calculate conditional VaR based on a chosen period (StartDate and EndDate) and percentile value. The prices that are used as input are stored in an Excel table on a separate sheet.

The function works fine when in debug mode, however, when I use it in a cell, it throws a %VALUE! error.
After adding some error handling code, it looks like the problem lies with the line setting the rngWorkrange (returns the error "Object variable or With block variable not set").
Any thoughts how to solve this issue?

Here the code:

```
Function C_VaR(ByVal StartDate As Range, ByVal EndDate As Range, ByVal ISIN As Range, ByVal PercentileValue As Range) As Double

Dim rngStartDate As Range
Dim rngEndDate As Range
Dim rngTargetFund As Range
Dim wsPrices As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim rngDates As Range
Dim rngFunds As Range
Dim rngWorkRange As Range
Dim arrPrices() As Variant
Dim arrReturns() As Variant
Dim arrTemp() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim dblPercentile As Double
Dim dblSum As Double
Dim lngCounter As Long

On Error GoTo Errhandler

Set wsPrices = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cijene")
Set tbl = wsPrices.ListObjects("tblCijene")
Set rngDates = tbl.ListColumns(1).Range
Set rngFunds = tbl.HeaderRowRange

Set rngStartDate = rngDates.Find(what:=StartDate, LookIn:=xlFormulas)
Set rngEndDate = rngDates.Find(what:=EndDate, LookIn:=xlFormulas)
Set rngTargetFund = rngFunds.Find(what:=ISIN, LookIn:=xlFormulas)

Set rngWorkRange = wsPrices.Range(wsPrices.Cells(rngStartDate.Row, rngTargetFund.Column), wsPrices.Cells(rngEndDate.Row, rngTargetFund.Column))

'Dump the range into a 2D array
arrTemp = rngWorkRange

'Resize the 1D array
ReDim arrPrices(1 To UBound(arrTemp, 1))
    
'Convert 1D to 2D
For i = 1 To UBound(arrPrices, 1)
    arrPrices(i) = arrTemp(i, 1)
Next

'Calculate the returns
For i = 1 To UBound(arrPrices) - 1
    ReDim Preserve arrReturns(1 To i)
    arrReturns(i) = arrPrices(i + 1) / arrPrices(i) - 1
    'Debug.Print WorkArray(i)
Next

dblPercentile = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile_Exc(arrReturns, PercentileValue)
 
dblSum = 0
lngCounter = 0
 
For i = LBound(arrReturns) To UBound(arrReturns)
    If arrReturns(i) < dblPercentile Then
        dblSum = dblSum + arrReturns(i)
        lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
    End If
Next i
 
C_VaR = dblSum / lngCounter * (-1)

Exit Function

Errhandler:
Debug.Print Err.Description
Stop
Resume


End Function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UDF works in debug mode but it doesn't give value into the cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71676039/udf-works-in-debug-mode-but-it-doesnt-give-value-into-the-cell)

Comment: I've got a feeling that `Find` is problematic in UDFs.  Trying to find documentation on it - closest is a comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48062479/using-find-in-a-user-defined-function-vba) question by Charles Williams:  _Early versions of Excel did not allow the use of Find in UDFs_

Comment: I have already tried to set the arguments to range, as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71676039/udf-works-in-debug-mode-but-it-doesnt-give-value-into-the-cell... still getting the error

Comment: Are all your other ranges setting properly, i.e. rngStartDate, rngEndDate, rngTargetFund? Using the .find might return Nothing.